# Kubuntu 20.04 - Notification flicker

Tags: kde, notification, flicker

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma 5.18.4

My issue is: The notifications are flickering and I want to get rid of this.
I tried various themes, compositors (OpenGL 3.1, OpenGL 2, XRender) and settings in Kvantum. Nothing helps.

It looks like this:

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding

`Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"` and

`Option "DRI" "3"`

to **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to fix it for me. Although, is there a way to verify for certain that the settings have taken effect? E.g. can you query the current `AccelMethod` and `DRI`?

Comment: I recently did a new clean install, so I don't have the settings I had, when the issue occurred. After a clean install, the problem did not occur at all.
Right now I don't even have the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` on my disk, at all.

Comment: `Option "DRI" "3"` worked on Ubuntu 20.04.